# preg_replace help: phone number

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need a little help here.  This code correctly displays every format I enter--except when it's xxx.xxx.xxxx

It keeps the periods in!  How do I filter out periods too?

```
preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2-$3", $phone_enter)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update the query so it will allow a **.** (dot), i added the `\.?` which means, a dot may appear zero or one time.

```
preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})\.?([0-9]{3})\.?([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2-$3", $phone_enter)
```

Comment: Yep, escape the dots and keep 'em outside of the groups.  I'd upvote but I've hit my limit already...

Comment: Yeah, there's a badge for hitting it, I think.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
preg_replace('/(\d{3})([.-])?(\d{3})\2(\d{4})/', '$1-$3-$4', $phone_number);
```

`\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`. The use of the backreference means you can enter "123.456.7890" or "123.456.7890" but not "123.4567890" or "123.456-7890".

Also bear in mind that other countries have different phone number formats, if that's relevant to what you're doing.

Comment: @cletus, the _\2_ means the second group again?

Comment: @Am: yes, that's the backreference. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html